# How authorization a proxy in chrome extension with mv3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

⚠ in **MV2** we using (`webRequest`) for proxy authorization . **and today some parts not working !**
google chrome suggested that we use (`declarativeNetRequest`) in **MV3**

Now my question is How to work with it ? ( for proxy authorization )

**Google chrome still gives me sign in alert**

My code is :

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "128": "./icon/128.png",
      "48": "./icon/48.png",
      "32": "./icon/32.png",
      "16": "./icon/16.png"
    }
  },
}
```

**rules.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "Proxy-Authenticate",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "Basic freeuser1:freeuser1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess Google forgot about proxy authentication for Manifest V3. Check this [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135492) for potential updates. Developers of proxy extensions with millions of users are gathering in that thread trying to get an update. It's sad.